# Javascript window.open file download callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the `window.open(downloadUrl, '_self')` to download a tar.gz file from server. I want to delete the same file form the server once either the download successful (by using the save button in file save dialog) or download was cancelled (by using the cancel button in file save dialog) by the user.

Are there any callback mechanism which I can use to get notify as soon as file written to client pc successfully or client cancelled the download?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the browser is handling the download once it starts and you don't have a hook into the success of that download. You might consider something like jQuery to download the file. Maybe something like the following. Here is a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/consultwithmike/e05nagur/).

**NOTE:** this is considered *experimental* technology and doesn't have support in all browsers.

```
var loc = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.js';
var url = '';

$('#output > a').on('click', function() {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    $('#output').empty();
    console.log('Revoked URL.');
});

$('#download').click(function () {
    $.get(loc, function (data) {
        var data = [data];
        var blob = new Blob(data, {
            type: 'application/javascript'
        });
        url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        $('#output').append('<a href="' + url + '" download>Save it!</a>');
    })
        .fail(function () {
            // delete the file - probably a $.ajax
            //$.ajax({
            //    url: 'url',
            //    type: 'DELETE'
            //});
        });
});
```

Comment: I am downloading a zip file using `window.open`. When I am using Blob method for downloading, the zip file gets corrupted and I am unable to open it. @mike